# Author on Discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm to make a discord bot that when you do !join it makes an embed where it put 6 people into teams. I want to make it so when it gets the 6 it says the person discord name instead of "player 1". How would I do this?

```
elif message.content.startswith('!join'):
global lobby
if (lobby == 5):
  lobby -= 6
  embed = discord.Embed(title="**Teams in the 6 Mans**", description="**Team 1** \nPlayer 1\nPlayer 2\nPlayer 3\n\n**Team 2**\nPlayer 4\nPlayer 5\nPlayer 6", color=0x0000FF)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed, )
```

Comment: You should really be looking at the commands extension and the rewrite branch tho

Answer (score 0):

Using globals is discouraged. That said, to access the discord username of the message author, you want to use `message.author.name`

Comment: How would I add that in a description?

Comment: `embed = discord.Embed(title="**Teams in the 6 Mans**", description="**Team 1** \nPlayer 1\nPlayer 2\nPlayer 3\n\n**Team 2**\nPlayer 4\nPlayer 5\n"+messsage.author.name, color=0x0000FF)` ?

Comment: Ok that works how would I make it so it has multiple names and doesn't only capture the last one who did the !join

Comment: You'd have to store them in a list, the format your title accordingly. I'm not going to spoonfeed you code, but you should have a look at for loops there :)